# How to format filed names with special character for AppInsight API filters?

Tags: c#, azure-application-insights

I am getting exception logs from Appinsight events following documentation at https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/Using-the-API/Events. The exception information is only available in appinsight/events, not in appinsight/query.

I want to apply filters on my custom fields by using URL like `"https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/DEMO_APP/events/exceptions?$filter=customDimensions%2Fmydimension%20eq%20'value'"` to talk to AppInsight.

But I have fields like "**My dimension**", "**User Name**" and "**Date/Time**", how can I handle the space and special characters in those fields to properly format them in the GET URL? (Using `%20` or `+` for space both returns error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

Solution 1:

put the field in [], like [my dimension]. And note that do not use double quotes within [], like ["my dimension"], which would result in parsing error.

Solution 2:

I suggest you can use `GET /query`, with that you don't need to worry about the space and special characters in the field.

Assume you have the field "My dimension" and "Date/Time" in the application insights logs, like below(note the query you write to query data):

[image]

Then in the [Azure Application Insights REST API explorer](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/apiexplorer/query?appId=DEMO_APP&apiKey=DEMO_KEY) site, click the "Get /query" in the left panel, input your **Application ID** and **API Key**, then in Query field, put your query(the query to query data in the above step) there. Click Fetch button, you can get your data.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Ivan for answering! I forgot to mentioned that I was looking for getting exception logs, which are not available in queries...

Comment: I'll take a look later. But I think you can also write query for exception logs.

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer back from MSDN forum: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/155b64a8-92fe-456e-b234-da98f8fec559/how-to-format-nested-field-name-containing-special-characters-when-filtering-appinsight-events-data?forum=ApplicationInsights.

The solution is wrap the field name using square brackets `[]` .